# RIA Services Exposing Property List<int> as IEnumrable<int>

Tags: silverlight, ria

I have a class used in RIA Services with a property of type

```
List<int>
```

This is being exposed as

```
IEnumerable<int>
```

Any reason why this can't be exposed by RIA as IList or just List?

IEnumerable is not the intended interface to be exposed.  Worse yet, the type coming back is an array int[] which when I convert to IList on the client it is of Fixed Size and therefore cannot be added to.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please post a copy of your property declaration, or the entire object declaration for the object you are working with. Also I would suggest you use an IList rather than List because it is more flexible and may give you a better reusability in the future.

Comment: I would post the property decleration, but it doesn't provide any additional value.

Answer (score 0):

A guess on why everything is exposed as IEnumerable instead of plain lists or arrays is because of the extended functionalities IEnumerable has.

It is very easy to convert IEnumerable to all other types of lists - arrays.
Just add the System.Linq namespace and use .ToList() or .ToArray() extenions on any IEnumerable instance.

Comment: The problem with this is that it makes a copy of the list and so you lose the connection to the original list.  Of couse you can work around it by re-assigning the IEnumerable property returned from RIA to a new value based on the original IEnumerable.  Example:  RIAObject.SomeList = New List(RIAObject.SomeList);

Comment: When dealing with intrisc types, the List<int> as an example is fixed size, so the list cannot be added to in your new list.  In this case, you would have to do some extra work on the client to be able to maniupulate the list data.